# Can I declare a function field in Ada JSON?

Tags: json, ada

Is it possible, with Ada, to implement the following JSON containing a function declaration `x: integer (float(x))`?

```
Example_JSON = "Integer": lambda x: integer (float(x))}
```

If so, how?
I've tried to find a method in GNATCOLL.JSON without success.

Answer (score 4):

It is impossible because a JSON value, according to [RFC 8259](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8259#section-3) can only be one of the following:

- null
- true
- false
- object
- array
- number
- string

You can put the function's source code into a string, and then parse that string at the receiving end, e.g. `{"integer": "lambda x: integer(float(x))"}`, but there's no *direct* way for a function to be a value in an object.

Comment: Thanks.  I think I seem to have mistakenly assumed a Python dictionary declaration to be a JSON declaration.